# How to satisfy between condition without using between in mysql

Tags: mysql

Without using Between operator, how to get the same result which is using between operator?

Comment: Use `>=` and `AND` and `<=`

Comment: @JohnConde is correct. The relevant MySQL documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the BETWEEN operator?

Answer (score 2):

The very first result of the search for "mysql between" is this

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

and it says:

> You can use BETWEEN clause to replace a combination of "greather than equal AND less than equal" conditions.

Comment: +1 for proof of the "gentle reminder" that this information is widely available :) The second result for "mysql between" is the MySQL "Comparison Functions and Operators" page; once click on the `BETWEEN` link there led to the link I posted in the comments above.

Comment: Anyother way to implement?

Comment: @Brindha there are many ways to implement in varying degrees of unnecessary complexity. Perhaps you should elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?